# Chrome extension popup refresh at the end of code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I programmed a chrome extension that works well (get cookie info on a specific page, fetch data and print in a textarea of my popup). But after add other checks, my popup stop printing my data.

I try to search why and I discover that my popup refresh as soon as my code ends. To test, I just code the below simple files and I still have the issue.

Just after installation, when I open my popup, I can see the "background" text in console log correctly. Good point.

But when I click on the button, I quickly see the text "test" in the console log but the popup immediately refresh then the console reset information and my button back again instead to stay invisible.

I don't know why the popup refresh when it did not do so before. Do you have an idea ? Is there something I do not understand ?

Thank you for your help.

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Test extention",
  "description": "Test extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "./img/icon_16.png",
    "32": "./img/icon_32.png",
    "48": "./img/icon_48.png",
    "64": "./img/icon_64.png",
    "128": "./img/icon_128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "./background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "./popup.html",
    "default_title": "Test Extention",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "img/icon_16.png",
      "32": "img/icon_32.png",
      "48": "./img/icon_48.png",
      "64": "img/icon_64.png",
      "128": "img/icon_128.png"
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage",
    "cookies",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
console.log("background");
```

popup.js

```
const startOfScript = () => {
  optionsForm.startlabel.style.display = "none";
  console.log("test");
};
optionsForm.startlabel.addEventListener("click", startOfScript);
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p class="title">Fred's AI Marketing extention</p>
      <form id="optionsForm">
        <button id="startlabel">Récupérer les données</button>
      </form>
      <script src="./popup.js"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `<form>`

Comment: Do you know why ?

Comment: Because its purpose is to send user data to the server. Extensions are local, they don't have a server, so the page just reloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer (Thank you @wOxxOm)

Just remove the `<form>` in popup.html

This node will automatically refresh the form and the popup at the same time.